# Only email and password for login

Tags: laravel, laravel-7

I have many attributes for the users' table. Admin needs to register a new user. My question is how to log in only with email and password?. my code now when user login user will get [this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ux6Os.png) and this [users database table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nKR08.png) . I only want to insert email and password when login in.

**Controller\Auth\AuthController.php**

```php
public function login(Request $request)
{
    if (!\Auth::attempt(['email' => $request->email, 'password' => $request->password])) {
        return redirect()->back();
    } else {
        return view('layouts.admin');
    }
}
```

**Http\UserController.php**

```php
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $user = new User();
    $user->Id_staff = $request['Id_staff'];
    $user->name = $request['name'];
    $user->noIc = $request['noIc'];
    $user->email = $request['email'];
    $user->password = bcrypt($request['password']);
    $user->pusat_tangungjawab = $request['pusat_tangungjawab'];
    $user->jawatan = $request['jawatan'];
    $user->user_group = $request['user_group'];
    $user->user_level = $request['user_level'];
    $user->phone_no = $request['phone_no'];
    $user->save();

    return redirect()->route('users.index');
}
```

Comment: you mean when the admin creates a User you get that error?   also you should put the error in your question as text

Comment: admin create user not get the error but when user want to login they will get the error like this SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'Id_staff' cannot be null (SQL: insert into `users` (`Id_staff`, `name`, `noIc`, `email`, `password`, `pusat_tangungjawab`, `jawatan`, `user_group`, `user_level`, `phone_no`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (?, ?, ?, amirul@gmail.com, $2y$10$KyfGs9GQ36M83jdx2TvPmelOy/VxXdyKmTbtirsYuhw9NyTgoMUUS, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, 2021-01-04 01:55:30, 2021-01-04 01:55:30))

Comment: why would a "login" cause a new user to be inserted into the database?

Comment: I mean admin register new user because user cannot register themself then admin give user information to login

Comment: well you have a field in the database that can not be `null` and you are passing it a `null` ... how would you like to handle that?

Comment: how to ignore null column?

Comment: you would have to allow that field to be `nullable` or set a value ... this is just a schema thing

Comment: is there any way to ignore value?

Comment: you can set the field as `nullable` on the table ... otherwise you have to set a value

Comment: Have you added `protected $primaryKey = 'Id_staff';` in your User model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you create a migration for users table, maybe the reason for that error because you didn't set nullable for `Id_staff`. So if you create a user and didn't post a value of `Id_staff` you will get that error. Some solutions is set a default value by random or set nullable in your migration, for example:

```
$table->string('Id_staff')->nullable();
```

Comment: Tq you help me a lots